# jQuery animate loop stuck in first loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do a simple animation on jQuery. The idea is moving a image to the right and then get back to where begin.

A made this code:

```
function logo(img) {
    $(img).animate( {
       left: 100
    }, 900, function() {
       $(img).animate({
          left: 0,
       }, 900,  logo(img))
    })
}
```

And this HTML

```
<div style="position: relative; width:500px; height: 55px; overflow: visible;">
<img class="pena" src="https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="50px" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0;" onclick="logo(this);">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rtfmu5za/1/

But in the first time time when the animation run, she get stuck for a little time. After that, everything works fine.

What I am mising?

Comment: By the way, this code will eventually produce `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, because you have infinite recursion. The stack size is ~10.4k calls for chrome and ~50.9k for firefox. That's probably enough, but it still might introduce errors with prolonged use of your page. And believe me, when debugging, you would hate yourself for this mistake.

Comment: Oh thank you! But this animation will not be forever. It's just a "loading" that i'll call sometimes. But I need to be and animation loop. Do you have any other way that I can do that?

Comment: If it's not infinite, it probably won't be a problem, but be careful, think about stack size. Honestly, I don't have any suggestion for jQuery, I've always done my animations with CSS3. If you're interested, [read more here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's indeed a strange problem with your code and I can't really explain why is this happening. Try this solution, works for me:

```
var position = 0;

function logo(img) {
    position = position == 0 ? 100 : 0;
    $(img).animate( {
        left: position
    }, 900, function () { logo(this) });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oqLakcbj/